# Why does using "ClaimTypes.Actor" return "actort"?

Tags: c#

I have the following:

```
/* create claims */
const string actorClaimValue = "actor";

SecurityToken sendToken = new JwtSecurityToken(
    claims: new List<Claim> {
        new Claim(
            type: ClaimTypes.Actor,
            value: actorClaimValue
        ),
    }
);

JwtSecurityTokenHandler sendHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

string sendTokenString = sendHandler.WriteToken( sendToken );

Console.Out.WriteLine( sendTokenString );
// eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJub25lIn0.eyJhY3RvcnQiOiJhY3RvciJ9.

/* get claims */
JwtSecurityTokenHandler receiveHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
JwtSecurityToken token = (JwtSecurityToken)receiveHandler.ReadToken( sendTokenString );

Claim actorClaim = token.Claims.FirstOrDefault( c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Actor );
Console.Out.WriteLine( actorClaim == null );
// True

foreach( Claim claim in token.Claims ) {
    Console.Out.WriteLine( "{0}: {1}", claim.Type, claim.Value );
    // actort: actor
}
```

Why does using `ClaimTypes.Actor`, which is defined as:

```
public const string Actor = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2009/09/identity/claims/actor"
```

result in a claim type of "actort"?

EDIT:

I just tried `ClaimTypes.Role` instead of `ClaimTypes.Actor` and it works... possible bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`JwtSecurityToken`s](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet/blob/c07d489fad3bd540202bf9459d30f66b9bcb9b14/src/System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt/JwtSecurityToken.cs#L164) [uses a mapping](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet/blob/328cbdc1be9b532e589d9e65ae9ebad71df13ff7/src/System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt/JwtPayload.cs#L446) found [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet/blob/e0039c68039d40afbbc33fbd488c62dc79a8dbbd/src/System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt/ClaimTypeMapping.cs#L149) that is the reverse [mapping of another map](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet/blob/e0039c68039d40afbbc33fbd488c62dc79a8dbbd/src/System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt/ClaimTypeMapping.cs#L121) that contains ["actort"](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet/blob/e6d903b4f8d3c6d7697dc70cd54ae905b18b65fe/src/System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt/JwtConstants.cs#L177).

Because I am using `JwtSecurityToken`s, I should use the mapping to find out what my resulting claim type value is before filtering it in `Claim actorClaim = token.Claims.FirstOrDefault( c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Actor );`